# How can I read 4 numbers as input from the user and print them as "|" separated values?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make a method to print out the elements in an array, separated by ‘‘|’’
@param values, an array of integers.

Essentially its suppose to take user input, and then from there separate it with |. This is what I have so far. Any help chaps?

```
    int [] scans = new int [3];

System.out.println("Enter 4 Numbers into the array: " );
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int s = scanner.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < scans.length; i++)
{
    scans [i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I assume this code doesn’t work, or you wouldn’t be posting about it. What *does* happen and what did you *expect* to happen? You should edit those into the question, preferably with actual sample input if the problem isn’t a compiler error.

Comment: This code gave no output. Compiler errors shouldn't be a reason for posting on this website.

Comment: You want 3 or 4 numbers? The array holds only 3, while you request the user to input 4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution that might be easier to understand without using the `mapToObj` solution @baao used (which is fine, but maybe harder to understand if your new to Java).

First of all if you want to store 4 numbers in the array, then your array should hold 4 not 3 elements. Another trick you can use is to create a prefix variable that is used to prepend each number in a loop over the values in the array. After the first iteration the prefix should be set to your separator variable.

You can see it working here: https://ideone.com/QCNPZQ

```
int [] scans = new int[4];
System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers into the array: " );
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i=0; i<scans.length; i++) {
    scans [i] = scanner.nextInt();
}

String prefix = "";
String result = "";
for(int i=0; i<scans.length; i++){
    result = result + prefix + scans[i];
    prefix = "|";
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're ignoring the first input number by assigning it to `s`, but you never use that thereafter. For the joining problem, you can use a stream. Below will ask the user to input 3 numbers, save them to your `int[3]` and output it joined by `|`

```
int [] scans = new int[3];
System.out.println("Enter 3 Numbers into the array: " );
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < scans.length; i++) {
    scans [i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
String joined = Arrays.stream(scans)
    .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));

System.out.println(joined);
```